set minor grid in a QCategoryAxis based chart
I have troubles using Qt's QCategoryAxis.
Preamble: I'm using this as a "poor man time axis", and I've created some code to basically define a new category for each first-of-the-month of the data I need to show.
It works fine, but now I have a grid with a column for each month. I want to have a 2-level grid: a major one each year and a minor one each month.
I know that the class support minorGrid* properties but the docs of the abstract class says:

Applies only to axes that support minor grid lines.

How do I know if QCategoryAxis supports minor grids?
If it does, how do I make them visible? I only see "major" ones.
If it doesn't (how I suppose) - is there a way to enhance QCategoryAxis to make it work?
FWIW: I'm writing a python application, using PySide (it's an internal app, so I may switch to PyQt if needed)

Could you provide minimal reproducible example so we can run and test it

If you have more control over your project and are comfortable with C++, you can create a custom axis class that inherits from QAbstractAxis and implements minor grid line functionality for categories. This would require a deeper understanding of Qt's charting mechanisms.

If you have more control over your project and are comfortable with C++, you can create a custom axis class that inherits from QAbstractAxis and implements minor grid line functionality for categories. This would require a deeper understanding of Qt's charting mechanisms.

I wish, if you could provide a minimal working code for your example (even for your first case)/

I think you can achieve better results with a 3D chart. With month in x direction, year in y direction and values in z direction.

Looking at the source code, reveals that minor axis are currently supported for 2 axis types:

QAbstractAxis::AxisTypeValue
QAbstractAxis::AxisTypeLogValue

For datetime and category axis, this feature isn't (yet) supported.
Note that it may be a good idea to submit a Qt bug report asking to update their documentation to include which axis types do actually support minor grid lines.

keep in mind that you're showing qt5 sources

moreover, it seems that the check you're linking is related only if the tickType() is QValueAxis::TicksFixed, but there is almost half method where the ticks are applied otherwise
